# Template Specifier With Zero Parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, zero

I have a class defined similarly to the following:

```
template< typename A, typename... B >
struct S {
    //...//
};
```

But I would like to create an overload (effectively) like so:

```
template<>
struct S<> {
    //...//
};
```

However the above is apparently illegal, I can not use a varidic template, and pass zero arguments to it because that could be ambiguous with the first definition (and bad practice). Is there a way to create  a template specifier with zero parameters in C++?

Comment: It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Loki Astari The use of this is going to be in recursion, I have an S constructor which instantiates another S as a member, as it recourse's the parameters get deduced until there are none left for B..., that is where I want the overload for S<> to come in.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to create a partial specialization that does not match the main template (the main template requires at least one argument).  If you want to use a variadic template, you can instead do:

```
template <typename... A>
struct S {
  // One-or-more case
};

template <>
struct S<> {
  // Zero case
};
```

Based on comments, the poster wanted to find the first argument for the non-empty case; the modification for that is:

```
template <typename... A>
struct S;

template <>
struct S<> {
  // Zero case
};

template <typename A, typename... B>
struct S<A, B...> {
  // One-or-more case
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Do you think there is a work around for this? I am looking for something to terminate my template recursion, which I need the first parameter for.

Comment: Try making the general template a forward declaration (no body) then having a partial specialization for one-or-more arguments.

Comment: To paraphrase: template<> struct S<>;, template< typename A, typename... T > struct S { /*...*/ }; ?